# realvnc username was not recognized or password incorrect

Tags: realvnc

When I login using vncviewer to vnc server it doesn't give me a user name in the login prompt, just a password. If I enter the password it won't log me in. I thought it might have a default username of admin and so only wanted a password, but no luck, see below.  Am I doing something wrong?  Did I misconfigure my vnc server in such a way that I can't login?

[image]

[image: failed login]

Comment: The only way I know how to resolve this problem is to check the logs on the server to determine what username is failing to authenticate.

Comment: Its been many years, but I recall RealVNC Server config has you put in an access password, that is not associated with any particular user, since VNC handles the authentication itself (or you can configure it to use some form of system-backed authentication like PAM or SAM). did you set an access password on the VNC Server config? that matches what your pictures show ("NOT your RealVNC account details", and that Username is greyed out). I also recall the VNC password being limited to 8 char.

Comment: is this one of the things where you login using the @ sign, like admin@password?

Comment: I reset the VNC server configuration and set the password to something simple.  After that I could login, but the user name is still grayed out.  It must automatically use the admin account and I was entering the wrong pwd.  I'm not sure how I would login using anything other than admin.

Comment: its not logging in as a windows user at all. the VNC Server Service is running, and responsible for providing the screen session. The password in question lets the service authenticate a VNC viewer request, but you are just authenticating with the service, not logging in as a user. In terms of how it executes on windows itself, the service and its running-user are actually responsible for taking the actions related to sharing the screen output and user input.